# Using global variable 'char **environ' to implement setenv() and unsetenv()

Tags: c, unix

I've been asked to (as a project) implement `setenv()` and `unsetenv()` in [c](/questions/tagged/c).

I'm doing this for a minishell I am building. I know I can access the environment variable directly (`extern char **environ`) 'cause I used it to implement `getenv()`.

My question, how do I add a value to the environ variable I indicated above?

I don't need code just an idea about how or links to places that could help, I can only use environ to do the implementations.

I've looked everywhere, found nothing. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a new variable to `environ` works like this:

1. Count how many variables the environment contains. Store this number in *n.*
2. Allocate a buffer for *n* + 2 pointers to `char`.
3. Copy the original `environ` to the new environment.
4. Append the new variable to the end.
5. Don't forget to terminate the array with `\0`.
6. Set `environ` to point to the new array.
7. If you allocated the previous `environ`, you can now `free` it.

In your own shell, you can do your own bookkeeping to make sure that you don't need to allocate new buffers for `environ` all the time (e.g. by allocating a slightly larger array and keeping tab of how many entries are free in it).

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want code (;

http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/book/proc/setenv.c.html

You can see that `setevn` uses `putenv` internally, which in turn uses `__add_to_environ` internal function to do this. See code for both here:

http://osxr.org:8080/glibc/source/stdlib/setenv.c

Comment: thank you, the code is simple enough to understand. however it only solves one of my problems (unsetenv()), i can not use putenv() to create setenv(). Thank you. @lshayPeled

Comment: You don't have to, see `__add_to_environ`